# SQL code to identify average daily totals

Tags: sql, sybase

I am puzzling over how to construct an algorithm to determine the average number of active clients in our system.  They have a variety of  information stored, id, contact start date, contact end date, account start and end dates, transaction dates, etc.  Not all of them have any consistent daily activity I could capture. I cannot figure out how to identify the number of active clients on a specific date.

I cannot change the structure of the db or modify tables substantially so I need to work with what I have.  One idea which I think does this is to check to see if the contact end date is greater than date X, or is null - and to check to see if the contact start date is less than date X.  I plugged that in but got the same number for any day I put in.   Is there another way to try this? I could add that code when I get to work but for now I submit this for consideration...

**Sorry..I left an important piece out.  I need to be able to identify the total active for any particular day in the past, then get a daily average totals for a year.   I may have resolved the first part of this with help from the posts below.  First I created a variable in my query to hold the date I need to search for...@report_dt

```
and contact_end_dt >= @report_dt
and contact_start_dt <= @report_dt
```

That piece did it for me.  Now I need to figure out how to loop through this over a years time and increment the @report_dt variable one day at a time.

Thanks for all the help...you are awesome!
Doug

Comment: This is SQL, don't go looking for loops.  Create a table with all 365/366 days that you're interested in, and join on it.  Or, total all the active days that appear in a year and divide by 365/366...  *[A is active for 365 days, B is active for 165 days, C is active for 200 day.  Average is 2.  It doesn't matter which days they were active on, only that you count days that fall in the year in question.]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could expand a bit by including:
- The code you tried but did not work
- The actual schema of your table(s)  *(Including datatypes, constraints, etc)*
- Example input and output data

That withstanding, the simple query it appears that you want is...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      (contact_start_date >= CAST('20120510' AS DATETIME) OR contact_start_date IS NULL)
  AND (contact_end_date   <= CAST('20120510' AS DATETIME) OR contact_end_date   IS NULL)
```

*(Though you may not need to check NULL start dates depending on your data constraints.)*

If that duplicates what you've already tried, I'll await any update to your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you do a query where sysdate is between contact start date and contact end date?

You have Conact Start date and contact end date, account start and end dates.  Can you rely on the data in the account start and end dates?  How long can an account have no activity before it is considered inactive?  If you can answer that question, you should be able to get to an answer.

Thanks, 
Susan

Answer (score 1):

Doug,

You haven't provided the faintest idea of what it means for a client to be "active." Once you figure that out, you can solve this problem.

Can you write a query that lists the active customers once each for, say, the date 2012-05-10? If so,

1. Create a separate table of dates, with one row for each day (or business day)
2. Use the query you wrote for 2012-05-10, but with a left outer join from the dates table. Select only dateTable.theDate, count(*) and group by theDate.

If you want something more specific, put something specific in your question. A rambling question without a single column or table name isn't going to get you much help. Take a look at questions here that get upvotes, please.

Comment: Thank you for the critique.  I understand it was a little vague :) Maybe it was too early to try to formulate a coherent thought.   I know better, I think!

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem.  The following query solves the problem using SQL Server and any database that supports row_nubmer(), assuming you have starts and stops on all dates:

```
with starts as 
(
   select start_date as thedate,
       row_number() over (partition by null order by start_date) as cumstarts
   from customers
),
ends as 
(
   select end_date as thedate,
       row_number() over (partition by null order by end_date) as cumends
   from customers
)
select thedate, cumstarts - cumends
from 
(
  (select * from starts) 
  union all 
  (select * from ends)
) t
group by thedate
```

Some databases offer cumulative sum directly, which makes it easier.

The problem is a bit tricker in SQL Server, when you have starts and stops on different dates.